# Weird that my remote ssh access open X window on the remote server but not on local client

Tags: macos, ssh, remote-desktop, x11-forwarding

I have setup my `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` on the server (Mac OS) as follows:

```
X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
X11UseLocalhost no
```

I can then from the client (another computer) `ssh -X myaccount@myserver.com` into the remote server. No error messages. The weird thing is that when I run an X window app on the server (e.g. emacs or safari or MS word), the X window actually opens on the display of the server! Not on the client!

I googled and studied, but it seems most people having problem with X11 remote access is that they cannot open an X window. Mine is different -- I can open an X window, but it's on the server side not on the client side.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Macos doesn't use X for its native display. I don't know about emacs, but programs like Safari and MS Word aren't using X to display windows, and they're not going to honor your SSH X forwarding.

Comment: Some good advice in these posts: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/378108/x11-not-forwarding-over-ssh-display-not-getting-set and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12755/how-to-forward-x-over-ssh-to-run-graphics-applications-remotely

Answer (score 0):

When you ssh into your server, run `echo $DISPLAY` to see what output it's pointing to. In this instance it's likely `:0`.

Did you restart the `sshd` service?

Make sure you have XQuartz installed on your client Mac and try `ssh -Y myaccount@myserver.com` instead.

Comment: echo $DISPLAY 

shows:

localhost:10.0

Yes, I even tried restarting both machines. But still, the X window opens on the server.

Thanks much!